# Fix blocked by CORS policy on firebase onCall

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

A frequent error I get when running firebase onCall functions is `... blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight ...`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the reason for this is that the function you are calling doesn't exist. Verify the name of the function you are calling, if you are sure that it exists delete the function from the console and call it again.

This method has worked for me every single time.

Do note that this is not the real reason this error ocurs, the fact is that this error is not telling us that the function is missing. It's just telling us that our request is being redirected to another domain. If you are having other CORS issues I suggest this [documentation by Mozilla on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)